# naming models in zend

Tags: zend-framework, naming-conventions, models

If i m not following the naming structure for the model name ( eg Application_Model_DbTable_Users in Users.php in model folder), i m getting error on controller.  instead of writing it as **Application_Model_DbTable_Users** , i want to write it simply as **Users** in Users.php in model folder. i know this is achievable in zend but how ?? i dont know. Please help in this concern. i guess something must be done in bootstrap.php or index.php for configuring autoloader.... whatever is the exact solution..... but please help me out for this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How do you know this is possible? The Zend Framework has a strict naming syntax to be able to load all files automatically. The autoloader uses the prefixes (like `Application_Model_`) to determine where the file is located. Without the prefix, this is not possible.

Sometimes during explanation of ZF's behaviour, it's too much work to type all the time `Application_Model_User` and instead of it, to make it more clear, things like `User` are used. This does not mean you can use this name in your application.

A last possibility is namespaces, but in the stable ZF it isn't used yet.

Comment: thanks for taking interest in the question ! i downloaded  a cms tomatocms from net. its open source and made in zend. in the code, they have changed the naming convention of the model and even they have not used any controller.php page in the controller folder. they have customized it very very well, but i m unable to understand their coding structure in few time. thats y i put the question here. tell me if you find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

ZF follows PEAR naming convention in that the folder hierarchy corresponds to the naming of the classes, e.g. Foo_Bar_Baz will be in the folder Foo/Bar/Baz.php. The autoloader will try to find this path relative to the configured include path.

This means, you can either put all your classes into a single top level directory already known by the Autoloader or put an additional include path or - and that's the better option - add an additional autoloader to the default autoloader that knows how to map class names to files.

Please refer to the [ZF Reference Guide on Autoloading](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)  for details.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement an custom autoloader which simply prepends the classname with the model path.
[in the documentation of the Zend_Loader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.load.html) there is an example on how to build your own autoloader plugin.
basically just an search & replace task.

However, i **strongly** recommend not using this approach, as your global namespace would be polluted a lot.
at least use a simple prefix (like Model_).